# Ionic 4+ and Codova File Plugin 6.0.2 can not be compiled

Tags: angular, file, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to build a simple file picker for one of my Ionic (web) project, to titrate some of images from project folder (at least for now).

So I decided to  use the "cordova-plugin-file" plugin --- version "^6.0.2".

As per the ionic documentation

`import { File } from "@ionic-native/file/ngx";` and    `providers: [....,File, FileOpener }],` in **AppModule**

`import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';` and `constructor(private file: File) { }` in **component/page**, is required further.

This should be pretty straight, however, when I tried to implement this, I get the following error and the compilation fails.

[image]

Terminal Log:

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
> [ng] chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.02 kB [initial] [rendered]
> [ng] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 127 kB [initial] [rendered]
> [ng] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
> [ng] chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 93 kB [initial] [rendered]
> [ng] chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 341 kB [initial] [rendered]
> [ng] ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:18:100 - error TS2322: Type '{ provide: typeof RouteReuseStrategy; useClass: typeof IonicRouteStrategy; File: typeof File; FileOpener: typeof FileOpener; }' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
> [ng]   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'File' does not exist in type 'Provider'.
> [ng] 18  providers: [StatusBar, SplashScreen, { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy, File, FileOpener }],
> [ng]                                                                                                       ~~~~
> [ng] Date: 2020-10-10T05:06:01.413Z - Hash: c963d31c2a4c95edc771 - Time: 8614ms
>
> [INFO] Development server running!
>
> ```
>    Local: http://localhost:8100
>
>    Use Ctrl+C to quit this process
> ```
>
> [INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:8100!

Please suggest a work-around
N Baua

Answer (score 1):

maybe its a version issue can you share your ionic environment or try to following steps

1). remove current file plugin from your project

2). npm install @ionic-native/file@4